Why does `Thread.Start` create a background thread in which `IsBackground` is false?
Suppose I create a background thread with this code:
var t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    //do something
}));

Within that thread callback method Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground is set to false. This doesn't make sense to me since I would have thought that the whole point of creating a thread is that it runs in the background.
Why does it work in this way? Can you ever create a foreground thread this way?

You can set IsBackround property to True after you create but before you start the Thread. See also Remarks section in this link: By default, the following threads execute in the foreground: All threads created by calling a Thread class constructor.

You can actually set it in the callback too, but my question is about why this is necessary. The thread is necessarily a background thread, so why doesn't the runtime set this property for you?

The thread is necessarily a background thread I think this may be the source of misunderstanding. Again, from the same link "A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread. Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating."

See also: Foreground and background threads

@Lesiak then i guess you could create a Thread to be run in the foreground, but (a) that doesn't seem to be the default behavior (b) why doesn't the runtime set this if it is in fact running in the background and (c) why would you want to make such a thing? If you're in the Main thread, why not just call the method, and if you're in the background, why not Invoke over to the main thread? Creating a foreground thread in this way seems like it would be an odd thing to do.

@JoshuaFrank, I think you're justifiably confused about the usage of the terms foreground and background here. In the context of C# threads, both kinds of threads are run independently (and in parallel) of the main thread, analogously to a shell's background process. The difference between foreground and background with regard to C# threads means something different: i.e. whether or not it will prevent the main process from terminating if it hasn't finished yet, as Lesiak and amir have pointed out.

The distinction again: foreground Thread - app will not terminate if there is such a thread running. This means that the job launched in such threads will run to completion. You most likely want this for your threads. Background thread - app can terminate while background threads are running. You typically set this property for threads that sit idle most of the time, and pull (receive) some tasks to perform. This is arguably a more specialized use case, and as such is not the default

"the whole point of creating a thread is that it runs in the background" The most general "point" of creating a new thread is to let it run concurrently with other threads. There are different reasons why you might want to do that, and people have different names for those different reasons. You are free to make up a new name if you think none of the customary names fit. "Background" is cool, but if you use it, just be aware, as other people have pointed out, that "background" also has a special meaning in the C# run-time.

I've been using threads for a long time and never realized what IsBackground means. What I thought it meant turns out to have nothing to do with what it does mean. Thanks for all the helpful comments here.

Foreground and background threads are identical and their difference is just in their termination, program execution lasts while a foreground thread is working but it doesn't care about a background thread. Following is a piece of Microsoft documentation about Thread.IsBackground Property which clearly says All threads created by calling a Thread class constructor will have IsBackground equal to false.


By default, the following threads execute in the foreground (that is, their IsBackground property returns false):


The primary thread (or main application thread).
All threads created by calling a Thread class constructor.


By default, the following threads execute in the background (that is, their IsBackground property returns true):


Thread pool threads, which are a pool of worker threads maintained by the runtime. You can configure the thread pool and schedule work on thread pool threads by using the ThreadPool class.
All threads that enter the managed execution environment from unmanaged code.


You can read more about it here.
